# Hi-Z state, MCU and transistors

Tags: bjt, brushless-dc-motor, tri-state

I have a 3-phase motor h-bridge.  The inputs to the motor require 3 different phases, `+`, `-`, and `0`.  I've got the circuit below that I'm using:

[image: Circuit]

The problem is that there are three states required:

- Q1 = Q2 = Low for `0`
- Q1 = High and Q2 = Low for `+`
- Q1 = Low  and Q2 = High for `-`

And typical logic is binary.  However, I would expect a High-Z state (meaning no current would be flowing), to be equivalent to "off" for both Q1 and Q2, since these are BJTs.  Is this something that can be depended on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, no current will flow (except leakage current) if the input is open, **provided** the output voltage stays within a diode drop of the rails.

If the output voltage is driven beyond the rails by two diode drops then the internal protection network of the driver could conduct some current, though the transistors will bear the brunt of it- so a series base resistor might be a good idea.

Comment: with the input disconnected and the output at 1.5V above VCC current flows through Q1 e-b then through Q2 b-c this turns on Q1 strongly and Q2 to a lesser extent (inverse beta being less than forwards beta) both transistors work together pulling the output voltage down towards ground and VCC (it is above both)